# Fixing a filemaker script with Embeded Applescript and Global Field

Tags: applescript, acrobat, filemaker

With a great deal of help from @Chuck I have written this filemaker script which is supposed to find related PDF attachments in container fields and export them to a temporary folder then trigger an applescript which will open & print the documents using adobe acrobat.

Unfortunately the script will not work and although I have used script debugger and tried to follow advice I am still having difficulty. Any assistance in telling me exactly where I'm going wrong would be appreciated.

```
Go to Related Record [Show only related records; From table: “Attachments”; Using layout: “Attachements Report" (Attachments); New window]
Enter Find Mode []
Constrain Found Set [Restore]
Sort Records [Restore; No dialog]
#
#After ﬁnding the related attachments and constraining them to the specific type we rename and export them to the desktop
#
Go to Record/Request/Page [First]
Loop
Set Variable [SPath; Value:"ﬁ|emac:" & Get ( TemporaryPath ) & Attachments::Record number &"-' & Attachment Type List 2::Preﬁx_z & Lien::Lien_lD_z]
Set Variable [SASPath; Valuei"/' & Substitute( SPath; "ﬁlemac:" & Cet( SystemDrive )1  )]
Set Field [Attachments::g_app|escript_parameter; $ASPath]
Export Field Contents [Attachments::ﬁle_c; “SPath"]
Perform AppleScript ['set _pdf_path to contents of cell "g_applescript_parameter" of current layout batchprint(_pdf_path) on batchprint(mycurrentﬁle) tell application ‘Adobe Acrobat Pro" activate —- bring up acrobat open alias mycurrentfile “'_*]
Go to Record/Request/Page [Next; Exit after last]
End Loop
Close Window [Current Window]
```

Using Script Debugger I get the following errors...

*On Script Step, Export Field* - Error: “ "(VARIABLE FILE NAME).. could not be created on this disk. use a different name make more room on the disk.

*On Perform AppleScript Step:* Error: Object not found & Error: Unknown Error: -1728

Comment: Please double-check your source code in the question. I think it just has typos, but I suppose it's possible that you're mixing up your variables names. One unfortunate feature of FileMaker is that when you reference a script variable name there's no check that you typed it correctly. The code you provide in the question shows setting the variable `SPath` (which FileMaker would convert to `$SPath`) and the variable `$Path`, which would be blank if your source code quote is correct.

Comment: @Chuck... You were correct  I was able to get the script to work. There was a space error in the $Path and since the document never got exported to the path, Acrobat couldn't open it... Hence the 2 errors. – Namaste.

Answer (score 0):

Is this being executed on the server (via a schedule) or on the client computer?

Have you verified that the directory permissions are actually set correctly in the temporary path?

Have you tried using `Get ( DocumentsPath )` instead of the temporary path, just to verify?

Comment: Not being executed on server. On local machine.   I have verified directory permissions.  I have tried both temporary path and desktop path. I am unfamiliar with documents path use...

Comment: This article refers to FileMaker Server, but the same method can be used on a regular FileMaker Pro client: http://help.filemaker.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/7035/~/import%2Fexport-script-on-filemaker-server

Also, did you try it with a manual export (instead of scripting the destination)?

Comment: I was able to get the script to work. There was a space error in the $Path and since the document never got exported to the path, Acrobat couldn't open it... Hence the 2 errors.